Problems in downloading CMCC ERA5 downscaling @2.2 km over Italy data with ddsAPI
I am trying to download with API the following data: https://dds.cmcc.it/#/dataset/climate-projections-rcp85-downscaled-over-italy/rcp45?
I copied the following lines in a python script
import ddsapi

c = ddsapi.Client()

c.retrieve("climate-projections-rcp85-downscaled-over-italy", "historical",
{
    "time": {
        "hour": [
            "00"
        ],
        "year": [
            "1981"
        ],
        "month": [
            "1"
        ],
        "day": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    "variable": [
        "precipitation_amount"
    ],
    "format": "netcdf"
},
"climate-projections-rcp85-downscaled-over-italy-historical.nc")

I got the following error output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fabiola/Documents/Università/PHD/LSPP/LSPP_po/data/api.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ddsapi
  File "/home/fabiola/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ddsapi/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import api
  File "/home/fabiola/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ddsapi/api.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .cache import CacheManager
  File "/home/fabiola/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ddsapi/cache.py", line 16, in <module>
    class CacheManager:
  File "/home/fabiola/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ddsapi/cache.py", line 17, in CacheManager
    cache_dir: str = field(kw_only=True)
TypeError: field() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kw_only'

